# How to select default option in material using Reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

Am having simple form using reactive, I can choose option using template driven forms, but I cannot do the same using reactive forms.
what am doing wrong here

```
<form [formGroup]="reactiveform">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Gender" [(value)]="gendervalue" formControlName="gender">
    <mat-option value="female">Female</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="male">Male</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</form>

<p>Form value: {{ reactiveform.value | json }}</p>
```

[live link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tssf2s?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: You don't need `value`. Set the chosen gender to the form control, i.e `gender`. Here I am assuming that you haven't done that :)

Comment: can i use form control in reactive froms? @Alex

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the link, but anyway as I said, set the value to the form control ;) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzaeoc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: this way is like hard coded, is there any other simple way.?

Comment: Well, if you want to use the variable `gendervalue`, then set that variable as the default value for your form control: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzaeoc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: let me add the project code @Alex

Answer (score 5):

Using a form group you should *not* set values through the inputs and outputs in the template. Instead you should do all manipulation of the form's data model using the [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) object in the typescript file. If you built your form group using the [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder), you might set the default value like this:

```
import {FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, ...) {
  ...
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.reactiveForm = this.fb.group({
    ...
    gender: myDefaultGender,
    ...
  });
}
```

You may then update the value by [.patchValue()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue)

```
this.reactiveForm.patchValue({ 'gender': myNewGender });
```

The parameter map may contain more than only one control's value. If you want to set *all* values at once you may also use the [.setValue()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setvalue) method.

Comment: How does this work if the list values come from a backend and you want then to put a default value selected?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done Angular, so my answer might not be up-to-date.

I'm not sure, what you mean by "default value selected"–from my understanding a selected value is the opposite of a default one. If you mean like displaying a certain thing, if the property sent by the backend is null or missing you might either update the formgroup accordingly on receipt of backend data (e. g. using the .patchValue()) or use a pipe (?) to transform the data for display. Use the pipe, if this is only about display.

Answer (score 0):

In ts file take one variable 'gendervalue' and assign default value to it as male or female whatever you want 
like 
In ts file

```
 gendervalue = 'male';
```

In HTML file
Form value: {{ gendervalue }}

check [this page](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#getting-and-setting-the-select-value) for more reference.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can set default select value when you creating form with FormGroup, if you don't need a FormBuilder.

For example set default value for gender:

```
    const genders = ['female','male']

    this.reactiveform = new FormGroup({
      gender: new FormControl(genders[0])
    });
```

patchValue() or setValue() - also good solutions if you want to set select value later after form creation.